# How saving function in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Edit : 
I have a function for generate a reference, in my controller and I'd save it returns at the same time add that my form is saved, but I would avoid spending the variable view and make a hidden input, how can I do? I try to use the model but without success!

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity){       
    if($this->Adverts->save()){
        $ref = $this->ref();
        $ref = $this->Adverts->reference;
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense, but I don't understand a single word. You really need to reword your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i edit my post !

Comment: Sorry, still have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: How i do for save in mysql a variable from my controller ?